# How to check which of my Contacts has Whatsapp in Capacitor app

Tags: android, whatsapp, capacitor

I am Currently working on a Capacitor app. I want to get the Information, which of my Contacts are using whatsapp. I can see that my Nativ Contact app of my phone shows me that information, that a specific Contact is available in Whatsapp.

Currently i am doing Following to read the Contacts data:

```
  const result = await Contacts.getContacts({
    projection: {
      name: true,
      phones: true
    }
  })
```

Now i want to know which Contact is using whatsapp.

I Know, that i can check if a single phonenumber is in whatsapp with this link

```
wa.me/<phonenumber>
```

is there any chance of getting this to work with multiple phonenumbers at once?